# data not bind from json for d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I am using D3 chart.

i'm using This d3 chart  :http://bl.ocks.org/diethardsteiner/3287802

In this chart all the data are read from variable. I want to read the data from json file.

I have complete the half of the work. I did same to complete the another half of the work but it is not working.

Pie chart is read data from json. but the bar chart is not to read data from json.

Here I have Created Plunker check this and give some solution.
https://plnkr.co/edit/TaXMsUWuIXe5kv3yzazk?p=preview

here what i tried to read data is not read from json.

I want to run this chart as same as this example:http://bl.ocks.org/diethardsteiner/3287802

> ## i tried like this

```
d3.json("data1.json", function(datasetBarChart){

debugger;
// set initial group value
var group = "All";

function datasetBarChosen(group) {
    var ds = [];
    for (x in datasetBarChart) {
         if(datasetBarChart[x].group==group){
            ds.push(datasetBarChart[x]);
         } 
        }
    return ds;
}


function dsBarChartBasics() {
debugger;
        var margin = {top: 30, right: 5, bottom: 20, left: 50},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        colorBar = d3.scale.category20(),
        barPadding = 1
        ;

        return {
            margin : margin, 
            width : width, 
            height : height, 
            colorBar : colorBar, 
            barPadding : barPadding
        }           
        ;
}

function dsBarChart() {
debugger;
    var firstDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);             

    var basics = dsBarChartBasics();

    var margin = basics.margin,
        width = basics.width,
       height = basics.height,
        colorBar = basics.colorBar,
        barPadding = basics.barPadding
        ;

    var     xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, firstDatasetBarChart.length])
                        .range([0, width])
                        ;

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()

           .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetBarChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])

           .range([height, 0])
           ;

    //Create SVG element

    var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("id","barChartPlot")
            ;

    var plot = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            ;

    plot.selectAll("rect")
           .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
           .attr("width", width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.measure);
            })  
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return height-yScale(d.measure);
            })
            .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
            ;


    // Add y labels to plot 

    plot.selectAll("text")
    .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
            return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
    })
    .attr("class", "yAxis")


    var xLabels = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height)  + ")")
            ;
    debugger;
    xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
          .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .text(function(d) { return d.category;})
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
                           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                                return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
                           })
          .attr("y", 15)
          .attr("class", "xAxis")
          //.attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
          ;         

    // Title

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right)/2)
        .attr("y", 15)
        .attr("class","title")              
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Elevator Trips by Material Stream and Destination")
        ;
}

dsBarChart();

 /* ** UPDATE CHART ** */

/* updates bar chart on request */

function updateBarChart(group, colorChosen) {
    debugger;
        var currentDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);

        var basics = dsBarChartBasics();

        var margin = basics.margin,
            width = basics.width,
           height = basics.height,
            colorBar = basics.colorBar,
            barPadding = basics.barPadding
            ;

        var     xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, currentDatasetBarChart.length])
            .range([0, width])
            ;


        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(currentDatasetBarChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
          .range([height,0])
          ;

       var svg = d3.select("#barChart svg");

       var plot = d3.select("#barChartPlot")
        .datum(currentDatasetBarChart)
           ;

            /* Note that here we only have to select the elements - no more appending! */
        plot.selectAll("rect")
          .data(currentDatasetBarChart)
          .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
           .attr("width", width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.measure);
            })  
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return height-yScale(d.measure);
            })
            .attr("fill", colorChosen)
            ;

        plot.selectAll("text.yAxis") // target the text element(s) which has a yAxis class defined
            .data(currentDatasetBarChart)
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return (i * (width / currentDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
           })
           .text(function(d) {
                return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
           })
           .attr("class", "yAxis")                   
        ;


        svg.selectAll("text.title") // target the text element(s) which has a title class defined
            .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right)/2)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("class","title")              
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(group + "'s Elevator Trips by Material Stream and Destination")
        ;
}
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

You are using wrong `d3.json` callback signature. The first argument of the callback is an error that occurred, or `null` if no error occurred, the second  argument is the returned data. So, you should use following:

```
d3.json("data1.json", function(error, data){
  if(error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // work with the data array
  }
}
```

The following code snippet demonstrates the loading of `dataset` from  an external JSON storage. When data has been loaded it is passed to the `dsPieChart` function that draws the above mentioned pie chart.

```js
d3.select(window).on('load', function() {
  // Loading data from external JSON source
  d3.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1hewit', function(error, json) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error('An error occurs');
    } else {
      dsPieChart(json);
    }
  });
});


// Format options
var formatAsPercentage = d3.format("%"),
  formatAsPercentage1Dec = d3.format(".1%"),
  formatAsInteger = d3.format(","),
  fsec = d3.timeFormat("%S s"),
  fmin = d3.timeFormat("%M m"),
  fhou = d3.timeFormat("%H h"),
  fwee = d3.timeFormat("%a"),
  fdat = d3.timeFormat("%d d"),
  fmon = d3.timeFormat("%b");

// PIE CHART drawing
function dsPieChart(dataset) {

  var width = 400,
    height = 400,
    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,
    innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
    innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius * .45,
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .data([dataset])
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);

  var arcFinal = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
  var arcFinal3 = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.measure;
    });

  var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "slice")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .on("click", up);

  arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure);
    });

  d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .delay(10)
    .attr("d", arcFinal);

  arcs.filter(function(d) {
      return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2;
    })
    .append("svg:text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.category;
    });

  function angle(d) {
    var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
    return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }

  vis.append("svg:text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Revenue Share 2012")
    .attr("class", "title");

  function mouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("d", arcFinal3);
  }

  function mouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("d", arcFinal);
  }

  function up(d, i) {
    updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));
  }
}
```

```css
#pieChart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.slice {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.title {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="pieChart"></div>
```

See also [Bar chart from external JSON file](http://bl.ocks.org/Jverma/887877fc5c2c2d99be10) example.

Comment: What is the reason of downvote? The runnable snippet works fine!